# mongo and mongod no longer works in terminal

Tags: node.js, mongodb

After upgrading to mac os Big Sur the mongo and mongod no longer works in the terminal. Mac os does not allow access to root /data/db anymore and this is causing this problem. I originally used brew to installed the mongodb-community6.0.
When I run mongod it gives me this:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.017-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.022-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.026-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.027-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.029-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.029-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.029-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.029-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.030-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":32260,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/usr/local/var/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"TJDs-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.030-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.0","gitVersion":"e61bf27c2f6a83fed36e5a13c008a32d563babe2","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.030-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"20.6.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.030-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1, ::1","ipv6":true},"storage":{"dbPath":"/usr/local/var/mongodb"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.031-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":5693100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Asio socket.set_option failed with std::system_error","attr":{"note":"acceptor TCP fast open","option":{"level":6,"name":261,"data":"00 04 00 00"},"error":{"what":"set_option: Invalid argument","message":"Invalid argument","category":"asio.system","value":22}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.031-05:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.031-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.031-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4794602, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Attempting to enter quiesce mode"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.031-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":6371601, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FLE Crud thread pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.031-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.031-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.031-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.031-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.031-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.031-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.031-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.032-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.032-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.032-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.032-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6278511, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the Change Stream Expired Pre-images Remover"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.032-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.032-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.032-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:02:14.032-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":48}}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.106-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.107-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.111-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.114-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.116-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.116-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.116-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.116-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.116-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":32359,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/usr/local/var/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"TJDs-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.116-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.0","gitVersion":"e61bf27c2f6a83fed36e5a13c008a32d563babe2","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.116-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"20.6.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.116-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1, ::1","ipv6":true},"storage":{"dbPath":"/usr/local/var/mongodb"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.117-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":5693100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Asio socket.set_option failed with std::system_error","attr":{"note":"acceptor TCP fast open","option":{"level":6,"name":261,"data":"00 04 00 00"},"error":{"what":"set_option: Invalid argument","message":"Invalid argument","category":"asio.system","value":22}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.117-05:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.117-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.117-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4794602, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Attempting to enter quiesce mode"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.118-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":6371601, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FLE Crud thread pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.118-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.118-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.118-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.118-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.118-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.118-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.118-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.118-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.118-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.118-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.118-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6278511, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the Change Stream Expired Pre-images Remover"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.118-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.118-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.118-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.118-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":48}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:56:15.491-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:65010","uuid":"4d045c63-ab76-40fb-a5a7-d1295dc87836","connectionId":14,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:56:15.497-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn14","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:65010","client":"conn14","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"4.8.1"},"os":{"type":"Darwin","name":"darwin","architecture":"x64","version":"20.6.0"},"platform":"Node.js v16.16.0, LE (unified)","version":"4.8.1|1.5.4","application":{"name":"mongosh 1.5.4"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:56:15.512-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:65011","uuid":"f2b0c1af-4706-4329-8111-f07091045c76","connectionId":15,"connectionCount":2}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:56:15.512-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:65012","uuid":"464841e1-8d99-4208-844b-beaafac78877","connectionId":16,"connectionCount":3}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:56:15.513-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn15","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:65011","client":"conn15","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"4.8.1"},"os":{"type":"Darwin","name":"darwin","architecture":"x64","version":"20.6.0"},"platform":"Node.js v16.16.0, LE (unified)","version":"4.8.1|1.5.4","application":{"name":"mongosh 1.5.4"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:56:15.514-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn16","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:65012","client":"conn16","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"4.8.1"},"os":{"type":"Darwin","name":"darwin","architecture":"x64","version":"20.6.0"},"platform":"Node.js v16.16.0, LE (unified)","version":"4.8.1|1.5.4","application":{"name":"mongosh 1.5.4"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:56:15.517-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:65013","uuid":"2395a617-f659-4a9b-a302-770e4c0e5c5c","connectionId":17,"connectionCount":4}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:56:15.521-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn17","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:65013","client":"conn17","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"4.8.1"},"os":{"type":"Darwin","name":"darwin","architecture":"x64","version":"20.6.0"},"platform":"Node.js v16.16.0, LE (unified)","version":"4.8.1|1.5.4","application":{"name":"mongosh 1.5.4"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:56:26.017-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:65018","uuid":"a73b9102-7685-45d5-ac00-22f08322d8c1","connectionId":18,"connectionCount":5}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:56:26.018-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn18","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:65018","client":"conn18","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"4.8.1"},"os":{"type":"Darwin","name":"darwin","architecture":"x64","version":"20.6.0"},"platform":"Node.js v16.16.0, LE (unified)","version":"4.8.1|1.5.4","application":{"name":"mongosh 1.5.4"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T23:12:11.169-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn18","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:65018","uuid":"a73b9102-7685-45d5-ac00-22f08322d8c1","connectionId":18,"connectionCount":4}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T23:12:11.169-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn15","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:65011","uuid":"f2b0c1af-4706-4329-8111-f07091045c76","connectionId":15,"connectionCount":3}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T23:12:11.169-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn16","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:65012","uuid":"464841e1-8d99-4208-844b-beaafac78877","connectionId":16,"connectionCount":2}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T23:12:11.169-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn17","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:65013","uuid":"2395a617-f659-4a9b-a302-770e4c0e5c5c","connectionId":17,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T23:12:11.478-05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4615610, "ctx":"conn14","msg":"Failed to check socket connectivity","attr":{"error":{"code":6,"codeName":"HostUnreachable","errmsg":"Connection closed by peer"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T23:12:11.478-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20883,   "ctx":"conn14","msg":"Interrupted operation as its client disconnected","attr":{"opId":69519}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T23:12:11.480-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn14","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:65010","uuid":"4d045c63-ab76-40fb-a5a7-d1295dc87836","connectionId":14,"connectionCount":0}}
```

I tried running mongod via path
`mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`
That didn't work.

I followed some articles to create another dir for data/db.

```
sudo mkdir -p /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
sudo chown -R `id -un` /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
```

Then start mongod via brew
`brew services run mongodb-community`
Then I should be able to use command mongo to access the shell but I can't.

I can however run mongosh but the db that I had work on is not on here. It only has admin, local, config.  I would like to get access to the db that I was working on and just use mongod to start the db.

In the usr/local/opt it has directories for

```
/mongodb-community
/mongodb-community@6.0
/mongodb-database tools
/mongosh
```

In usr/local/var there are directories for

```
/hombrew
/log/mongodb
/mongodb
```

Comment: you should provide all logs (or at least a reasonable last part of it) since you just printed that a server is terminated but not why

Comment: this is a clue: `{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-08T22:22:14.117-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":5693100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Asio socket.set_option failed with std::system_error","attr":{"note":"acceptor TCP fast open","option":{"level":6,"name":261,"data":"00 04 00 00"},"error":{"what":"set_option: Invalid argument","message":"Invalid argument","category":"asio.system","value":22}}}`, I think it's something in your config

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the `mongodb-community@6.0` via brew:

```
brew uninstall mongodb-community 
brew uninstall mongodb-database-tools
brew uninstall mongosh
brew untap mongodb/brew
```

Then reinstalled it via brew again.

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew update
brew install mongodb-community@6.0
```

I believe the problem was that the instructions that I was following from other articles was for MongoDB that was installed via a downloaded file directly from MongoDB website (`.tgz`)

When you install it from brew then you can't use `mongod` or `mongo` as a command anymore. You strictly have to use the brew commands to start and stop `mongod`.

```
brew services run mongodb-community@6.0
brew services stop mongodb-community@6.0
```

The way to still use `mongod` to start up MongoDB is via using aliases.
So instead of that long brew command to start and stop the MongoDB I made a `.zshrc` file in the home directory (`/Users/<username>/.zshrc`):

```
alias mongod='brew services run mongodb-community'
alias mongod-status='brew services list'
alias mongod-stop='brew services stop mongodb-community'
```

Now I can start the MongoDB via `mongod`. Then use the `mongosh` command as the shell to interact with the database.

Comment: Sounds like your `$PATH` isn't set up right, I have `mongodb-community@6` installed on my Mac and I can run `mongo` and `mongod` just fine.

Comment: Did you install mongodb-community@6 trough homebrew?

Comment: Yes, I did. The CLI commands get installed in `/opt/homebrew/bin` for me (M1 hardware, on Intel they get installed in `/usr/local` by default).